# angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-template, 2-way-object-databinding

I have attached the plunker of my angular2 code piece. I want to print a field from my JSON but unable to print that as initially my Object is null and it is being populated via a Promise.

This is my component file

```
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

class MyData {
  xyz : MySubData;
}

class MySubData {
  name : string;
} 
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

      {{abc.xyz.name}}
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  abc : MyData = null;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.abc = new MyData();
      this.abc.xyz = new MySubData();
      this.abc.xyz.name = "Binita";
    }, 2000);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I am removing the line `{{abc.xyz.name}}` from my template it is running fine.

I have use set time out in my code because I am getting my data from Promise (i.e asynchronous call).

I can understand initially as `abc` is `null`, my code is unable to find abc.xyz.name. But I don't want to put any if condition to check. Because I have several property inside a JSON and it is not possible for each property to write if condition.

Earlier in angularjs 1 if abc is null then it would automatically replace it with blank string. I want to do the same thing in angular2. Please suggest.

Below is the plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/u1NqNF0penz7OS55QmoU?p=preview

Answer (score 126, accepted):

That's because `abc` is undefined at the moment of the template rendering. You can use safe navigation operator (`?`) to "protect" template until HTTP call is completed:

```
{{abc?.xyz?.name}}
```

You can read more about safe navigation operator [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator).

Update:

Safe navigation operator can't be used in arrays, you will have to take advantage of `NgIf` directive to overcome this problem:

```
<div *ngIf="arr && arr.length > 0">
    {{arr[0].name}}
</div>
```

Read more about `NgIf` directive [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

Answer (score 0):

Safe navigation operator or Existential Operator or Null Propagation Operator is supported in Angular Template. Suppose you have Component class

```
  myObj:any = {
    doSomething: function () { console.log('doing something'); return 'doing something'; },
  };
  myArray:any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myArray = [this.myObj];
  }
```

You can use it in template html file as following:

```
<div>test-1: {{  myObj?.doSomething()}}</div>
<div>test-2: {{  myArray[0].doSomething()}}</div>
<div>test-3: {{  myArray[2]?.doSomething()}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the best way in angular is utilizing `resolver` guard. this guard help you get data before rendering view, while now you rendering data first then you get data, that's why you face with such an error. I prepare a video on YouTube, you can get idea there. follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=naAji0AjjDs)