# ionic 2 - Display data in template after it’s loaded from Promise

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise, ionic2

I'm using File plugin function `readAsText()` to convert my JSON file to string, then parse it to object and simply store it in a local variable which i then want to display in HTML template. Problem is the function `readAsText()` returns a Promise so when I'm displaying the variable its still undefined and data hasn't loaded yet.

My home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
})

export class HomePage {
    object: any;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public file: File,
    ) {
        // process that returns string, parses it into object and saves it into variable "object"
        this.file.readAsText("file:///android_asset/www/assets/json", "Choosing_Values.json")
        .then( result => {
            this.object = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log("Object: ", this.object);      // data is loaded
        }).catch( err => console.error("file wasn't read", err));
      }
```

And my HTML template:

```
<ion-content>
...

<p>Object: {{object.COMPANY.COPMANY_NAME}}</p>     <!-- the data is still undefined because the promise hasnt assigned the value in time-->

...
</ion-content>
```

How can I "wait" for the promise to finish loading the data, and display the variable only after it contains the object with the data ?

Comment: Safe navigation operator is one possibility, or *ngIf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined

Comment: I think you can do this: `object?.COMPANY?.COPMANY_NAME`

Comment: Presumably `COPMANY_NAME` is a misspelling, and should be `COMPANY_NAME`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the variable is defined:

```
<p *ngIf="object">Object: {{object.COMPANY.COPMANY_NAME}}</p>
```

or using the elvis operator:

```
<p>Object: {{object?.COMPANY.COPMANY_NAME}}</p>
```

in the component:

```
export class HomePage {
    object: any = null;
}
```