# View is rendering before API response is ready from subscribe

Tags: angular

I am fetching data from API response,

The problem is sometimes html renders before Response ready from `subscribe()`.

so the problem is html doesn't load data it appears blank. its important here to load html only after API response is ready.

Here is my service

**service.ts**

```
getItinerary(){
        let params={
            "Module_SRNO": "",
            "Screen_SRNO":"",
            "Type": "Itinary",
            "Unit": 0 ,
            "Location": 0,
            "Branch":"0",
            "UserId": 0,
            "Ip": "0",
            "Corporate": this.corporate,
            "InquiryCode": this.InquiryCode,
            "QuoteCode": this.QuoteCode
            }
        return this.http.post(this.url,params)
        .map(res=>res.json())
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
getItinerary(){
    this.quoteService.getItinerary()
    .subscribe(itinerary => {
      this.itinerary = itinerary.resultData.Itinary;
      this.Itns = asEnumerable(this.itinerary).GroupBy(x => x.CheckinDay,  x => x,
         (key, b) =>          
         { return { 
           CheckinDay: key ,itineraries: asEnumerable(b).ToArray() }
            })
        .ToArray();  
    },
    response => {
     if (response.status == 404) {
        }
    })
  }
```

I'm using `ngOnInit` for calling function

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getItinerary();
}
```

also tried to call function from `constructor` also

**component.html**

```
    <section id="itinerary" class="itinerary-section page-section" >
   <div class="itinerary-section-title">
      <h3><span>tour</span> ITINerary</h3>
      <span>Highlights Of Your Journey</span>
   </div>
   <div class="itinerary-section-detail flex-container">          
      <div class="flex-container-detail">
         <div class="itinerary-section-slider">                    
            <div class="itinerary_carousel">
               <div class="carousel-indicators">
                  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" data-slide="prev">
                     <span class="icon-prev"></span>
                  </a>
                  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic3" data-slide="next">
                     <span class="icon-next"></span>
                  </a>
               </div>
               <div id="carousel-example-generic3" class="carousel slide">
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                     <div class="item" class="item" [class.active]="i === 0" *ngFor="let itinerary of Itns;let i = index">
                       <div class="itn-left">
                        <div class="itinerary-img">
                           <img src="{{imgURL}}/{{itinerary.itineraries[0].BackgroundImg}}" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <div class="itn-right">
                        <div class="day-circle">
                           <div class="itinerary-date">Day {{itinerary.itineraries[0].CheckinDay}}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                           <div class="itn-detail">
                              <div class="itinerary-tour">
                                 <div class="itinerary-tour-title">       
                                    <h4>{{itinerary.itineraries[0].CityName}}</h4>
                                    <span>{{itinerary.itineraries[0].CheckinDate | date}}</span>
                                 </div>                                          
                                 <div class="itinerary-tour-detail">
                                    <div class="itinerary-tour-detail-in mCustomScrollbar" data-mcs-theme="dark" >
                                       <div class="row">
                                          <div class="col-md-6" *ngFor="let itn of itinerary.itineraries; let i = index ">
                                             <div class="itinerary-tour-detail-wapper c{{i+1}}">
                                                <div class="itinerary-tour-detail-wapper-icon">
                                                   <img src="assets/icons/{{itn.Icon}}.png" alt="">
                                                </div>
                                                <span>
                                                   <p>{{itn.Checkintime}}</p>
                                                   {{itn.IternaryText}}
                                                </span>                                                
                                             </div>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12 row">
                                       <div class="itinerary-tour-detail-wapper-btm-txt" >
                                          <div class="col-md-8" *ngFor="let itn of itinerary.itineraries; let i = index ">
                                           <div *ngIf="itn.ItenaryFor === 'Sightseen' || itn.ItenaryFor === 'Sightseen'">
                                             <div class="rating-icon" ><img src="assets/images//rating-icon.jpg" alt=""></div>
                                             <p>Sightseen :</p>
                                             <span>{{itn.TourDelight}}</span>
                                          </div>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--Slider-->
   </div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

How can I make sure that view render only after response is ready?

Comment: What does your html look like?

Comment: You should rather make your view so that it doesn't break when the data is not yet available, but it's hard to make suggestions without more details what your view looks like and what error you get. Instead of `subscribe()` you can use the `| async` pipe in the view.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer updated question with html

Comment: Try to make a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and please add the exact error message.

Comment: Your template is probably giving errors because you are not doing truthy checks. Change your nested object interpolations like this `{{itinerary?.itineraries[0]?.BackgroundImg}}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I have to use `subscribe` cause I have to do some grouping of response

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya you can replace `subscribe` with `map`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  So, I can do everything in `map` what I'm doing in `subscribe`? and I'm already doing `map` in service

Comment: You can chain as many `map` or most other Rx operators, but `subscribe` can only be call once.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer and without `Observable` its possible to use `async`?

Comment: @NikhilRadadiya not sure what you mean. If you don't have an Observable (or a Promise) there is no point in using `| async`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150940/discussion-between-nikhil-radadiya-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a simple service that do not load the page until all component is ready. Look for this:

```
import {EventEmitter, Injectable} from '@angular/core';

      @Injectable()
      export class LoadPageService {
          private isReady= false;
          // Event emitter that make event each time the variabe isReady changes
         Updated: EventEmitter <boolean>= new EventEmitter();
        setdata( value) {
          this.isReady = value;
            this.Updated.emit(this.isReady);
        }

          getdata() {
          return this.isReady;
        }

      }
```

And in you component do this:

```
       ` isReady:boolean;
         ngOnInit() {
        this.isReady = false;
       this.loadpage.setdata(this.isReady);

    this.httpService.GetPic('/manger').subscribe(
      (data: any) => { 

      // You code Here to get data from server or other API

       this.isReady = true;
       this.loadpage.setdata(this.isReady);


      }
  }
```

`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not getting, can you please explain a bit further?

Comment: In you Html code use  ngIf and make the rending of the html depend on isReady Boolean. This Boolean do not  not become true until the API finish and return data.

Comment: what if I have multiple functions of service call in a page?

Comment: It will work only when you change the value of isReady variable. It  worked for me.

Comment: It's working for one section, but I have multiple section in a page and multiple service call in same component

Comment: I think if I set `isReady= true` in second function its overwriting

Comment: You have to update the value of variable in the service using:
           this.loadpage.setdata(this.isReady);

since service is a singleton in angular it will update  automatically using the event emiiter.

Comment: ZAhmed can you have a look at this
https://gist.github.com/NikhilRadadiya/856040b19671a91941a64410a0018ad0

Comment: I see the code and it need only to call the loadpage function with TRUE argument .You question is where to put  this.loadpage.setdata(this.isReady) ??

Comment: yes I have multiple functions, where should I call it?

Comment: Make a function that wait for all previews function to end and return true , then make the value  of  isReady true

Comment: can you show me an example what you are trying to say, please?