# Undefine data from angular4

Tags: angular

I am trying to dynamically navigate to the course from the list of courses facing the issue as undefine data please help me to resolve the issue. 
Issue:  name is undefined.

```
services : 
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import{ICourses} from '../model/courses.model';

@Injectable()
export class CoursesService { 
      private coursesUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/courses';
      constructor(private http: Http) {
      }

    getallCourses(){ 
      return this.http.get(this.coursesUrl)
        .map((res : Response) => res.json())
      } 

    getCourseDetail(name: string) : Promise<ICourses> {
        const url = `${this.coursesUrl}/${name}`;
         console.log(url);
           return this.http.get(url)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json().data as ICourses)
          .catch(this.handleError);

    } 

    private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}



component : 


import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {CoursesService} from '../../services/courses.service';
import{ ICourses } from '../../model/courses.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-course-detail',
  templateUrl: './course-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-detail.component.css']
})
export class CourseDetailComponent implements OnInit {
   icourses : ICourses;

  constructor(
    private coursesService: CoursesService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() : void {
    this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParamMap) =>
      this.coursesService.getCourseDetail(params.get('name')))
      .subscribe(icoursesData => this.icourses = icoursesData )        
  }

}

HTML : 

{{icoursesData.name}}
```

Comment: What is the result if you display `params.get('name')`?

Comment: what are you trying to display.?Please post your html code as wel

Comment: i am taking an http request to get the data ; the request has _id ,name and body as column. name is the ural parameter that i am passing : http//localhost:8000/courses/course1 -- name is fetched from the url ()as dynamic link . by using this url i need to check unique record as http request and trying to display on component html as {{icourseData.name}} . there is no htmal script other than that

Comment: the result of is params.get('name') it will changes dynamicaly through link -- course1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)