# API data not displaying properly (Ionic/Angular)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I make calls to an API and assign the response data to the `games[]` array, like below:

```
export class HomePage {
  games = [];
  genre: any;
  genreName: string = 'Upcoming Games';
  favorites = [];

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private _data: DataProvider,
    private storage: Storage,
    public loading: LoadingController,
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    let loader = this.loading.create({
      content: 'Loading Games..',
    });

    loader.present().then(() => {
      this.storage.get('genre').then(val => {
        if (val) {
          // console.log('Val is equal to ', val) testing purposes
          this.genre = val;
          this.genreName = 'Shooter';
        } else {
          this.genre = 5;
          this.genreName = 'Shooter';
          this.storage.set('genre', this.genre);
        }

        this._data.getGames(this.genre, 0).subscribe(res => (this.games = res));
      });

      this.storage.get('favorites').then(val => {
        if (!val) {
          this.storage.set('favorites', this.favorites);
        } else {
          this.favorites = val;
        }
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        loader.dismiss();
      }, 1200);
    });
  }
}
```

In `home.html`, I am able to successfully display the data on the webpage by using the following expressions:

`{{ games[1] | json }}` **or** `{{ games | json }}`

but I am not able to display specific objects from the json response like this:

`{{ games[1].id | json }}` **or** `{{ games.id | json }}` **or** `{{ games[1].id }}` **or** `{{ games.id }}`.

With these, I get this error:

> "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined".

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: How about this: {{ games[1]?.id}} using the safe navigation operator?

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much! I'm just now learning about safe navigation operators. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)