# cant populate selector, Cannot read property 'name' of undefined,

Tags: angular, http

Im trying to get some fields from BE to map over in to my FE class. 
I then want the name on the fields to populate a selector and its options.

Here is the service

```
export class FieldsService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  public getFields(): Observable<Response> {
    return this._http.get('/api/fields');
  }
}
```

Field.class

```
export class Field {
    public name: string;
    public id: string;
}
```

Component.js

```
export class Component implements OnInit {

  public _fields: Field;

  constructor(private _fieldsService: FieldsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._fieldsService.getFields()
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(result => this._fields = result);
  }
}
```

and last but not leaste, Component.html:

```
<pre>{{_fields | json}}</pre>
        <div class="form-group" *ngIf="_fields !== undefiend">
          <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Fields</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" ng-repeat="let field in _fields">
            <option>{{field.name}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>
```

Im guessing that Im doing something wrong with the mapping.
Been reading tutorials but cant see what im doing wrong.

Br

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try replacing your ng-repeat directive with *ngFor directive.

```
<pre>{{_fields | json}}</pre>
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="_fields !== undefiend">
   <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Fields</label>
   <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" *ngFor="let field of _fields">
       <option>{{field.name}}</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

I guess you could use .subscribe() method without mapping datas.

You noticed I used "let field of _fields" instead of "in", because in watches for indexes whereas of watches values.