# Angular2 nested http get request

Tags: angular

I have two APIs api/resource/Item which returns

```
{data: [
{name: "BE106359"},
{name: "NDBKR5050"}
]}
```

and for Item details api/resource/Item/{name} which returns

```
{
data: {
net_weight: 0,
max_discount: 0,
item_name: "NEC | BE106359 | CD-PRTA - ISDN PRI TRUNK BLADE, SV8xxx",
website_warehouse: "Stores - CT",
default_material_request_type: "Purchase",
disabled: 0,
name: "BE106359"
......
}}
```

my angular2 code to iterate through details but print undefined value so couldn't get any value on my HTML template

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductsService  {
  getProductDetails() {
    return this.http.get("https://domain/api/resource/Item")
      .map(
      p => {
        let products = p.json().data;
            products.forEach(m =>
          this.http.get('https://domain/api/resource/Item/'+ m.name)
          .map(details=> details.json())
          .subscribe(details => details.data) // <-- get values when trying to console print out 
       );
      });
  }}

//calling service from component
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  products;

  constructor(private service: ProductsService) {
    this.service.getProductDetails().subscribe(products => this.products = products); // <---- console.log(products) print undefined value
  }}
```

Comment: Well, there is no local variable `products` where you have your commented out console.log, so it shouldn't even compile. What is the **actual** code you're executing? Do yourself a favor, and specify the return type of your methods. You'll see that your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The callback to your outer map, `p => ...`, *doesn't actually return anything*.

Comment: `this.products = products` and not `this.products == products`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem all I need `mergeMap`

```
getProductDetails() {
    let Products: any[] = [];

    return this.http.get('https://domain/api/resource/Item')
      .map(res => res.json().data)
      .mergeMap(list => list)
      .mergeMap(name => {
        return this.http.get("https://domain/api/resource/Item/" + name['name'])
      })
      .map(res => {
        Products.push(res.json().data)
        { return Products; }
      })
  }

//then call it from my component
this.service.getProductDetails().subscribe(res=>this.products= res );
```