# angular 5: How do I wait for my service to finish and then proceed to the next task?

Tags: angular, rest

I have a component in my angular5 application called: `product-list.component.ts`. In this component, I have a constructor, which calls a REST API.

**product.service.ts**

```
getAllProductsFromACategory(categoryName: string): any {
this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/VespaWebshopAPI
/api/Article/Category?categoryName=' + categoryName).
subscribe(data => {
var article: Article = {
    id: data[0].id,
    name: data[0].name,
    articleNr: data[0].articleNr,
    stock: data[0].stock,
    price: data[0].price,
    description: data[0].description
  };

  return article;
});
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
public article: Article;

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private productService: productService) { 
 //Call rest api
 this.article = 
 this.productService.getAllProductsFromACategory('Bremsen');
}
```

**article.ts**

```
export interface Article {
id : number;
name : string;
articleNr : string;
stock : number;
price : number;
description : string;
}
```

In my HTML, I want to display some properties of an article. So if I try to run this code in my **product-list.component.html** file, I get the following error:

```
{{ article.id }}
```

**Error**

> ProductListComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'id' of undefined
> at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProductListComponent.html:1)
> at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14727)
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13841)
> at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
> at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14119)
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13842)
> at callViewAction (core.js:14187)
> at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14145)
> at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13837)
> at callViewAction (core.js:14187)

The REST API works; I tested it. I guess there is just the problem that the data should get loaded first before the HTML page gets displayed. Somewhere else I read that in an `ngFor`, I should make use of the | async pipe, but that didn't work for me.

So how do I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Update your question to refute that it isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@TNII, @Hoang Duc, try say you is that generally a service expose Observables. It's in a ngOnInit in your component when you subscribe to the Observable.

```
//Simple return a get
getAllProductsFromACategory(categoryName: string): any {
   return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/VespaWebshopAPI
   /api/Article/Category?categoryName=' + categoryName)
}
```

In the component, generally in an ngOnInit when we subscribe to

```
ngOnInit()
{
    productService.getAllProductsFromACategory('Bremsen').
      subscribe(data => {
         if (data[0])
             this.article=data[0];
      })
}
```

the {{article?.id}} wrote in the html is a abreviate way to say: if this.article is defined, show me this.article.id.

check if when in a navigator write http://localhost:8080/VespaWebshopAPI
/api/Article/Category?categoryName='Bremsen', give you an array of Articles. Check if the elements of the arrays has properties id,name,etc (or return element with another properties)

Answer (score 6):

In `productService.getAllProductsFromACategory()` replace `subscribe` with `map` so that the method returns `Observable<Article>`

In `constructor` of `product-list.component.ts`, subscribe to the `Observable<Article>` returned from `productService` and set value for `this.article` in that

```
this.productService.getAllProductsFromACategory('Bremsen')
    .subscribe((art: Article) => {
        this.article = art;
    },
    (err: any) => console.error(err));
```

In your html, put an `*ngIf="article"` in the surrounding element of your interpolation `{{ article.id }}` to prevent it from processing until `article` obtains a valid value.

Comment: you can solve your problem write {{article?.id}} too

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im trying to implement that, but I can't figure out, why I can't return "Observable<Article> in my getAllProductsFromACategory method. Could you maybe also help me there?

Comment: It's rxjs `map` method that returns an Observable, not what returned inside that `map` method. So you need an extract `return` statement that returns what `map` returns.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the template is trying to use a data which is not available yet. Before accessing it, the server's response must be completed. So, in order "to wait and avoid that error", i did a similar trick that worked fine.

I wrote a conditional directive on the surronding element. Doing that, "while **data_from_server** is null", template does not try to get the info and does not produce the fail.

```html
<div style="text-align:center" *ngIf="data_from_server">
  <form>
    <label for="name">NAME</label> 
    <input [(ngModel)]="data_from_server.nombre" name="nombre">
  </form>
 </div>
```

Comment: But Purpose is to get data , not to hide input element

Comment: @Saurabh The thing is "you can't show any data in your template until it be available on the component". So, the trick is you show nothing, meanwhile data is retrieved from the server.

Comment: "the trick is you show nothing" - really ? , what about async pipe , observable and promise ?

Comment: @Saurabh this forum is for helping people, not for questioning or assess negatively things that you can't understand. My response solves the question asked. I don't have to explain observables, pipes, http protocol or other things related. Try to study more, be more humble, and expose your questions properly

Comment: I am really sorry if you feel it was personal on you. But it was not . And regarding your answer , hope yo have checked answer given by Eliseo to use subscribe method as Op want to show information not to hide if it is not available . One more thing i completely agree with you about "this forum is helpful" . But if our answer is not even close to problem than we should avoid it putting as answer , maybe can put as comment but not as an answer.

Comment: Dear @Saurabh, please, before posting, review the original question (not only focus your attention on the answer you are interested in) and you will notice that it talks about a rendering problem on the template. "in my product-list.component.html file, I get following error:

{{ article.id }}

Error

    ProductListComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProductListComponent.html:1)" So, you are totally wrong from the beginning when you say "But Purpose is to get data ". No, no, no!. Stop wasting people's time