# Angular 6 Waiting service response before render template

Tags: angular

I can't resolve this problem. Anybody know what happens here?

My CategoryService is

```
  getCategory(): Observable<Category[]> {
    // return this.http.get<Category[]>("/category");

    return this.http.get<Category[]>(this.endpoint)
  }
```

And here is my edit-category component

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService, Category } from '../services/category.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-category',
  templateUrl: './edit-category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-category.component.scss']
})
export class EditCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private categoryService : CategoryService, private router: ActivatedRoute ) { }
  category : Category;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.categoryService.getCategory().subscribe((data : Category[]) => {

            this.category = data.filter(res => {
              return res.id == params["id"]
            })[0];
            console.log(this.category)

          });
   });

  }

}
```

I need to call category in my edit-category-component.html .

```
<p>
  {{category.Adi}}
</p>
```

I can do this but after that or meanwhile browser says 4 times (I have 4 record) . But my code showing after that 4 errors record. Code works, so how these mistakes are made.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Adi' of undefined
```

I'm new at angular. This is looks like promise or ngOnInit?
And sorry I realy dont know How can I write true question.

Comment: Since you're already using router... this is what route resolvers are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the null safe operator instead:

```
<p>
  {{category?.Adi}}
</p>
```

This will prevent the error you're seeing when category is null / undefined. You can read more here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: You can wrap it in a div, and add `ngIf="category"` That way the elements wont be added to the DOM until category is defined

Comment: I already get results for edit my record. But I need to understand why this errors is showing me? My problem is like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250528/angular-5-how-do-i-wait-for-my-service-to-finish-and-then-proceed-to-the-next-t?rq=1

Comment: No problem, please feel free to accept this as the answer if it has solved your problem

Comment: This is like "hack"? Or one shot solution?

Comment: No, not at all. If you read that link, it's one of the things they suggest (although the recommend to use `?.` where possible, but it can't be used for 2 way binding)