# Ensure a service is done before going furthure

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to ensure that my service is done before going to other functions as I need its result to be used. I have seen some solution, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250528/angular-5-how-do-i-wait-for-my-service-to-finish-and-then-proceed-to-the-next-t/48251631), but did not work.

here is what I code:

My service:

```
  getText(){ return this.http.get(this.textURL, {responseType: 'text'}); }
```

I called it as follows in ngOnInit:

```js
ngOnInit()
{


    let spaceIndex=0;
    this.readJsonService.getText().subscribe((data) => {

         for (const line of data.split(/[\r\n]+/)){
        //   console.log(line);
           spaceIndex=line.search(/\s/);
        //   console.log("spaceIndex  " + spaceIndex)
           this.weakness.push({
             CWE_ID: line.substring(line.search('CWE-'), spaceIndex),
             weakness: line.substr(spaceIndex)
           })
          }
            console.log(this.weakness.length)
            console.log(this.weakness)
       });


 this.trythis();
}
```

and in tryThis() function, I want to log the result, which is in weakness that is a global interface. like so:

```
  console.log(this.weakness.length); console.log(this.weakness)
```

but it first runs the Trythis() function, so gives an empty array and says the length is 0, while running yet the service. and then logs the array from the ngonInit functiom.
please please help. thank you in advence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the statement ' this.trythis();' as follows,

```
    ngOnInit() {


        let spaceIndex=0;
        this.readJsonService.getText().subscribe((data) => {

             for (const line of data.split(/[\r\n]+/)){
            //   console.log(line);
               spaceIndex=line.search(/\s/);
            //   console.log("spaceIndex  " + spaceIndex)
               this.weakness.push({
                 CWE_ID: line.substring(line.search('CWE-'), spaceIndex),
                 weakness: line.substr(spaceIndex)
               })
              }
                console.log(this.weakness.length)
                console.log(this.weakness)

                this.trythis();
           });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Life-cycle hooks doesn't exist on injectables. So instead of using life-cycle hooks like ngOnInit in @Injectables, use the constructor.

```
@Injectable()

  constructor() {
      //your code
  }
```

Comment: True. I have done that, the problem was I has called the function tryThis outside the service.