# Angular 5.2.6 HttpResponse access on html template error

Tags: angular, angular5

Getting error while accessing HttpResponse data in html template, i am able to access value on html page but getting error as well

```
ProfileComponent.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_profile' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProfileComponent.html:1)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14693)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13807)
at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13808)
at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.js:14111)
```

my code

```
data:any = {}
this.authService.getUserProfile(this.username)
    .subscribe (
        res => {console.log(this.data = res);
```

so i am accessing in template

```
{{data.body.user_profile.bod}}
```

getting value fine but getting error as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined/41242804 `{{data?.body?.user_profile.bod}}`

Comment: Superb its working

Comment: Great! Since it worked fine, I marked the question as a duplicate :)