# How to Display Values in Angular 8 Shows ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, angular8

My ts code coding is,

```
this.api.getPay(this.donationId).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.paymentData = data;
        this.paymentDetails = this.paymentData.donationDetails[0];
    }
)
```

My html code is like

```
Project :   <strong>{{paymentDetails.project_name}}</strong><br/>

Status:     <strong>{{paymentDetails?.status}}</strong><br/>
```

Now `project_name` and `Status` details will be displayed. Console gets `"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined"`

If I added "?" like

```
{{paymentDetails?.project_name}}
```

No Details displayed. But console not having any Error.

This same coding method works well in Angular 5/6.

Any special method for Angular 8 ???

Comment: Can you share your response data?

Comment: this.api.getPay(this.donationId).subscribe(
    data => { console.log(data); });
Please share the above console data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Comment: ```{
project_name: "test",
status: "true"
}``` this is Console output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectiongStrategy.OnPush
```

as per https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/
this will resolve the Error

Answer (score 0):

When the view is first rendered, the variables are not set (will be undefined);

Once your service returns the response to the call `this.api.getPay(this.donationId)`, the variables are set to what they need to be.

your options are:

1) place a ngIf arround the block with the variables in your template:

```
<ng-content *ngIf= "!!paymentDetails">
Project :   <strong>{{paymentDetails.project_name}}</strong><br/>

Status:     <strong>{{paymentDetails?.status}}</strong><br/>
</ng-content>
```

2) Change the controller to set variables as observables and use the async pipe:

```
this.getPay$ = this.api.getPay(this.donationId)
```

and

```
Project :   <strong>{{(getPay$ | async).paymentDetails.project_name}}</strong><br/>

Status:     <strong>{{(getPay$ | async).paymentDetails.status}}</strong><br/>
```