# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined - Angular 8

Tags: angular8

My ts code coding is,

```
this.api.getPay(this.donationId).subscribe(
    data => {
        this.paymentData = data;
        this.paymentDetails = this.paymentData.donationDetails[0];
    }
)
```

My html code is like

```
Project :   <strong>{{paymentDetails.project_name}}</strong><br/>

Status:     <strong>{{paymentDetails?.status}}</strong><br/>
```

Now `project_name` and `Status` details will be displayed. Console gets `"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined"`

If I added "?" like

```
{{paymentDetails?.project_name}}
```

No Details displayed. But console not having any Error.

This same coding method works well in Angular 5/6.

Any special method for Angular 8 ???

MY console output in TS file is

```
{
project_name: "test",
status: "true"
}
```

Previous question is [How to Display Values in Angular 8 Shows ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'project_name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58776788/how-to-display-values-in-angular-8-shows-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property/58776948#58776948)

but solution not working

anyone know how to resolve ?

Comment: what happens if you print `paymentDetails` in the html ?
try to replace  
`<strong>{{paymentDetails.project_name}}</strong><br/>`
 with
`<strong>{{paymentDetails | json }}</strong><br/>` for debug purpose

Comment: @dco {
project_name: "test",
status: "true"
} displayed

Comment: @dco any solution ?

Comment: Everything seems good, check if your component doesn't have `changeDetection: ChangeDetectiongStrategy.OnPush`
If yes, remove it and change put back the '?' in the html markup, and then add it back and do the change detection in the subscribe.

Comment: @dco I added as per https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/. My Error Resolved. Thank you

Comment: Ok then i change it as answer so you can resolve

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems good, check if your component doesn't have

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectiongStrategy.OnPush
```

If so, remove it and put back the '?' in the html markup, and then add it back and do the change detection in the subscribe