# Angular 9: Type Error product is undefined

Tags: angular, undefined

Here, defining a product that is undefined in the beginning.

`private Products: product[];`

Products is the array of the product interface which is defined in another class

```js
getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
      res => { 
        this.Products = res
      },
      (error) => { console.log(error.error.message) }
    )
  }
```

and calling the service that adds data inside this array in the ngOnInit method

This variable is undefined and I cannot use the safe navigation operator here.
I tried to use the `*ngIf` but that doesn't seem to work.

```html
<div *ngIf="!(Products == undefined)">
      <tr *ngFor="let product of Products | async ; index as i">
      <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
      <td><img class="mr-2" src="{{ product?.image_url }}" height="50" width="50"></td>
      <td>{{ product?.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ product?.description }}</td>
      <td>{{ product?.price | number }} $</td>
      </tr>
    </div>
```

I had already used *ngIf in more than 3 ways and had read other posts about the same issue but my problem was not solved.

I tried this method but it doesn't work. This is the error I face every time I use an array in angular.

[angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

I hope this time I will know the correct answer to this problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: there is a convention to name properties starting from lowercase and names of classes and interfaces from uppercase. `private products: Product[];` would be aligned with this convention

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would be great if you can give the proper solution

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it. The `async` pipe is used with an array. It is supposed for Promises or Observables.

Comment: No this is not the case. Interface product is imported and working

Answer (score 0):

You are doing both, using `async` and subscribing in the controller. It should be either of the one.

### Option 1: using `async`

Controller

```js
Products: any;

getProducts() {
  this.Products = this.productService.getProducts();
}
```

Template

```html
<div *ngIf="Products">
  <tr *ngFor="let product of Products | async; let i = index">    <!-- using `async` here -->
    <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
    <td><img class="mr-2" src="{{ product?.image_url }}" height="50" width="50"></td>
    <td>{{ product?.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product?.description }}</td>
    <td>{{ product?.price | number }} $</td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

### Option 2: subscribing in the controller (no `async`)

Controller

```js
public Products: product[];

getProducts() {
  this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
    res => { this.Products = res },
    error => { console.log(error.error.message) }
  );
}
```

Template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="Products">
  <tr *ngFor="let product of Products; let i = index">   <!-- no `async` here -->
    <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
    <td><img class="mr-2" src="{{ product?.image_url }}" height="50" width="50"></td>
    <td>{{ product?.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ product?.description }}</td>
    <td>{{ product?.price | number }} $</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Use `<ng-container>` for simple checks. They are compiled as comments and no additional elements are added to the DOM.

Comment: by doing this `private Products: product[] = [];` you will not need to add `*ngIf` because if there is nothing inside `products, the `*ngFor` will not loop through that html code.

Comment: em.... the author already informed that he tried this approach. and it couldn't. an empty array is truth, so `*ngIf="Products"` would always be true. and the error is 'product is undefined', not 'Products is undefined'

Comment: I am also using ng-bootstrap and declaring it initially to empty I cannot use paginantion.

Comment: `> 1` or `> 0` ? in `Products.length > 1`

Comment: @PulkitBanta: I've edited the answer. Please see if it works for you.

Comment: @HDJEMAI Products is undefined so this approach doesn't work here.

Comment: @PulkitBanta - You should make a stackblitz, so that everybody can work on the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I've reproduced your code example in the following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vssmhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html), check to see how I'm able to show the Products without any undefined issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vssmhg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

In your case, if the value returned from the service is undefined, means the value of `res` equals to undefined, then there might be some issue with the service, and you can try to do something like:

```js
this.productService.getProducts().subscribe(
    res => { 
        if(res) {
          this.Products = res;
        } else {
          this.Products = [];
        }
    }, (error) => { console.log(error.error.message) })
```

Comment: It works because you initialized `public Products: Product[] = [];` and without this, the code will not work.

Comment: You have to do this, even when you will write unit test, you will have many issues if you don't initialize your class fields.