# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectName' of undefined

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I cant figure it out where the problem is. This is my template:

```
<h1>Details for {{ project.projectName }} </h1>
<h6>Project Description: {{ project.description }}</h6>
<h6>Project Stage: {{ project.stage }}</h6>
<hr />
<app-employee-list></app-employee-list>
<app-tickets-list></app-tickets-list>
```

This is the service where i get a single project:

```
interface GetResponse {
  _embedded: {
    projects: Project[];
  };
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root",
})
export class ProjectService {
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/projects";
  renderRoleAssignment$: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.renderRoleAssignment$ = new Subject<boolean>();
  }

  getProjectList(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<GetResponse>(this.baseUrl)
      .pipe(map((response) => response._embedded.projects));
  }

  getProject(id: number): Observable<Project> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Project>(this.baseUrl + "/" + id);
  }
}
```

This is the project class:

```
export class Project {
  id: number
  _links?: Links;
  projectName: string;
  description: string;
  stage: string;
}

export class Links {
  self: { href: string };
}
```

And this is my component:

```
export class ProjectDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  project: Project;
  getProjectSub: Subscription;
  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/projects/";

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private projectService: ProjectService
  ) {
    this.getProjectSub = new Subscription();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.projectService.renderRoleAssignment$.next(false);
    this.listProject();
  }

  listProject() {
    const projectId = this.route.snapshot.params["id"];
    this.getProjectSub = this.projectService
      .getProject(projectId)
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.project = data;
        console.log(this.project)
        this.addIdToProject(projectId);
        console.log(this.project.id)
      });
  }

  addIdToProject(id: number) {
    this.project.id = id;
    console.log(this.project.id)
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.project.id = id;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.getProjectSub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

The stack trace of the error:

```
core.js:4196 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'projectName' of undefined
    at ProjectDetailsComponent_Template (template.html:1)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7446)
    at refreshView (core.js:7315)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8453)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7108)
    at refreshView (core.js:7365)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:8407)
    at refreshView (core.js:7339)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:8453)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:7108)
{projectName: "Game App", description: "A simple game", stage: "Completed", _links: {…}}
1
1
```

So as you can see from the logs the project is there, the id that i add are defined.
But for some reason it cant find the project properties and display them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular2: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property '...' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41242793/angular2-error-typeerror-cannot-read-property-of-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is whats going on**: You are declaring `project: Project` at the top. Your html is trying to read a property off of `project` it is not defined yet so thats why you get `Cannot read property 'projectName' of undefined` as that call is made in the `NgOnInit` and is async.

**Here is how to fix it as long as your service call is returning the correct data**: Short way: Initialize project at the top. Long way: It would be a good idea to make `Project` an interface and call it `IProject` then create a class called Product that implements `IProject`.

```
export interface IProject {
  id?: number
  _links?: Links;
  projectName?: string;
  description?: string;
  stage?: string;
}

export class Project implements IProject {
constructor(
  public id: number,
  public _links?: Links,
  public projectName?: string,
  public description?: string,
  public stage?: string,
){}
}
```

Then in your component html:

```
  project: IProject = {};
```

and of course in your service:

```
getProject(id: number): Observable<IProject> {
    return this.httpClient.get<IProject>(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }
```

finally in your html using the optional chaining operator:

```
<h1>Details for {{ project?.projectName }} </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks i implemented the longer way and im gonna add it to the other components too. The only problem is that if i reload the page i get this error and nothing is displayed: 

```
GET http://localhost:4200/projects/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: It seems like you need a way to serve static files. I can't speak too much for a solution on that as I dont know your architecture or anything but I would start by googling "serve static files with node/java/.net/ etc"

Comment: well is just a personal project i select a project and i show the assigned employee component and tickets component aswell as the project detail. But this page only get thes this error

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, we should be using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) wherever possible. In this case, this would save you some trouble:

```
<h1>Details for {{ project?.projectName }} </h1>
```

or if it makes more sense

```
<h1 *ngIf="project?.projectName">Details for {{ project.projectName }} </h1>
```

This error is thrown because you have declared project variable, but initialised it asynchronously some time after angular tried to render the view.

The same of course is valid for the rest of your html, wherever you are trying to access an object property that might be null or undefined.

Comment: thanks a lot it would have worked ofc, i implemented the longer solution tho.